# Can virtual machines in Proxmox copy files directly from real machines?

Tags: proxmox

I installed a virtual machine on the Proxmox server, and now I find that when LOGGING in to the virtual machine using my client, I cannot copy files (such as photos, text) from my local computer to the virtual machine. How can I set the connection between the client and the VIRTUAL machine as VMware virtual machine?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see above you seem to use some kind of macOS. You could seek a remote client that has the capability for drag and drop. Like ultravnc's file transfer.
Maybe you should check out something like anydesk ( if you are not concerned where your data goes).

I would use this:
Activate ssh on the VM. Use your favourite ssh client to copy files from/to the machine.

Comment: Using SSH is a good idea because it's Windows, which I didn't think of at first.